# What do you call a medical procedure that requires the patient to recover walking

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

For some medical operations its required to revalidate the patient because the procedure was so heavy he/ she had to lie down for 1 to 3 weeks with a completely paralysed lowerbody. After the patient is health they need physiotherapy to relearn walking.

What is this phenomenon called.

Comment: I have been a physician for decades, and this question makes no sense to me. There are penty of reasons patients need physiotherapy after surgical proceedures, but recovery from prolonged induced paralysis is not one with which I'm familiar.

Comment: The patient has not walked for a long time and needs therapy to relearn walking. Most of the time it takes just 3 days of physiotherapy.

Comment: Fiso therapy sounds like using the jacuzzi.

Comment: If the question is unclear to a doctor, it's certainly unclear to me. Voting to close; reopen after editing to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Rehabilitation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/rehabilitation):

> the action or process of rehabilitating or of being rehabilitated: as
>   the physical restoration of a sick or disabled person by therapeutic measures and reeducation to participation in the activities of a normal life within the limitations of the person's physical disability

If the person just needs rest, it is called **Convalescence**

Comment: @sirwilliam - Is this what you are seeking?

Comment: I agree with this.  I would say the patient needs "rehab" or "PT", which are common abbreviated terms for rehabilitation and physical therapy, respectively.